# pause program between adding and removing a TextView

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a tank-game and I have a `TextView` which represents the shot. Now I want to display the `TextView` at the specific point and remove it after a second that it looks like the shot goes further step by step. But when I add a countdown or a `Thread.sleep` the program stops for a second but the `TextView` doesn't disappear. i want to move the TextView over the screen and after every iteration of my for loop i want to wait a second and then rearrange it again?

Here is the code :

```
 public void shot(float power, float winkel, Button button) {

        if(winkel>90) {
            winkel = winkel - 10;
        }else if(winkel<90){
            winkel = winkel +10;
        }
        for (double i = 0; i<100;i = i+ 1) {

            final TextView textView = new TextView(context);
            textView.setText(".");
            double x = tanks.get(currentTank).getxPos()+(i*power*Math.cos(winkel *(Math.PI/180)));
            double y = tanks.get(currentTank).getyPos()+(-1*(i*power*Math.sin(winkel *(Math.PI/180))));
            double gravity = (-1*((9.81/2)*Math.pow(i,2)));
            y = (y-gravity);
            textView.setX((float) x);
            textView.setY((float) y);
            layout.addView(textView);



            for (int j = 0;j<tanks.size();j++){
                if(textView.getX()>tanks.get(j).getxPos()&&textView.getX()<tanks.get(j).getxPos()+100){
                    if(textView.getY()>tanks.get(j).getyPos()&&textView.getY()<tanks.get(j).getyPos()+100){

                        float k = tanks.get(j).getxPos()-textView.getX();
                        if(k<0){
                            k = k*-1;
                        }
                        makeDamage(k,tanks.get(j));
                    }
                }
            }
            new CountDownTimer(2000,1000){

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                }
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    layout.removeView(textView);
                }
            }.start();
        }
        newTurn();
    }
```

I want to pause the program after adding the `TextView` for one second and the remove it. The program stops but the `TextView` doesn't disappear till the for-loop finished. Then all `TextViews` disappear.

**Problem solved:**
i've added all positions in a array and then this

```
public void drawShot(final Button firework, final ArrayList<TextView> toDraw){
    final int[] i = {0};
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    firework.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            firework(firework,toDraw.get(i[0]).getX(),toDraw.get(i[0]).getY());
        }
    });


    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

                layout.addView(toDraw.get(i[0]));
                if(!check(toDraw.get(i[0]))) {
                    mHandler.postDelayed(this, (long) 1);
                }
                i[0]++;

        }
    };

    // start it with:
    mHandler.post(runnable);

}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to achieve. Your code now executes the for loop and then starts the timer. After the timer has finished it removes the `TextView`. In what order do you now want to execute it?

Comment: i want to dislay the tetView and remove it a second later. that it looks like the shot go further step by step

Comment: Please keep in mind that for someone who's not involved into the conception of your app it's really hard to understand explanations like this. Could you explain code related when your `TextView` should be displayed and removed? Right now it is removed 2 seconds after the countdown is started, so it sounds like you just need to rearrange your code a little.

Comment: the texView represent a projectil and in the for-loop the position of this projectil gets calculated with i as time. i want to achieve that one round throw the loop represents one second of flyingg time. now when i execute the method you just see the flight path. but i want to get this flight path step by step

Comment: Ah I think I'm starting to understand what you're trying. So you're trying to move the `TextView` over the screen and after every iteration of your for loop you want to wait a second and then rearrange it again?

Comment: exactly! sorry my english is not the best

Comment: No problem, sometimes it just can take time to understand the issue! why don't you put the countdown into your for loop then?or create a method that starts a timer and call it on every iteration?

Comment: i have two for-loops. and the countdown is in the outer loop and the inner loops check if the shot hits a tank

Comment: Now I understood it. The problem is that the countdowns are added right after another and are executed as they should but after the loops have already finished. So the for loop runs through and simply creates the timers which then execute their code. Since they all do the same you just don't see that there are multiple timers running. I've never heard of a way to make a loop delay like this, I could only show ways to execute an inner for loop with a delay, but not both as you need it.

Comment: i thought i use a SwingWorker(sperate Thread) do you think that will work?

Comment: I don't know, you can try anything. Otherwise you might want to change your concept a little!

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: I did a little research again and think you can find an answer in this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58320761/my-java-object-constructor-returning-null. The problem with using `Thread.sleep` isn't that it wouldn't work, it's just that it sleeps the UI Thread, so you won't be able to manipulate any UI elements. This is bypassed here. You can integrate your code there, the general construct works fine.

Comment: nice idea. but i've solved it in another way. i've edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably need to run the remove command on main thread

```
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());

Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override 
    public void run() {
       layout.removeView(textView);
    } 
};
mainHandler.post(myRunnable);
```