# how to delay this for-loop

Tags: java, android

i'm working on a tank-game and for this i want to display the shot on the screen. The shot should move over the hole screen second by second and it should move smooth from one side the other but it just rush from one side to the other. i go 20 times throught the for-loop and want to stop if for 1 second but if i click the shot-button the textView disappears and show up 20 seconds later in on the other side.
How can i delay this loop and move the textView step by step over the whole screen that it looks like a shot? i've tried Threads, Runnable and Countdowns without succed.

Here is my shot-function

```
public void shot(final int power, float winkel, Button button) {
    if (winkel > 90) {
        winkel = winkel - 10;
    } else if (winkel < 90) {
        winkel = winkel + 10;
    }

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final float finalWinkel = winkel;
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (double i = 0; i < 20; i = i + 1) {
                TextView textView = new TextView(context);
                textView.setText(".");
                double x = tanks.get(currentTank).getxPos() + (i * power * Math.cos(finalWinkel * (Math.PI / 180)));
                double y = tanks.get(currentTank).getyPos() + (-1 * (i * power * Math.sin(finalWinkel * (Math.PI / 180))));
                double gravity = (-1 * ((9.81 / 2) * Math.pow(i, 2)));
                y = (y - gravity);
                System.out.println(x + "/" + y);
                textView.setX((float) x);
                textView.setY((float) y);
                textView.setTextSize(50);
                layout.addView(textView);

                if (textView.getY() >= 400 && i > 2) {
                    System.out.println("BOOOOOOOM");
                    displayExplosion(textView.getX(), textView.getY());
                    break;
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < tanks.size(); j++) {
                    if (textView.getX() > tanks.get(j).getxPos() && textView.getX() < tanks.get(j).getxPos() + 100) {
                        if (textView.getY() > tanks.get(j).getyPos() && textView.getY() < tanks.get(j).getyPos() + 100) {

                            float k = tanks.get(j).getxPos() - textView.getX();
                            if (k < 0) {
                                k = k * -1;
                            }
                            makeDamage(k, tanks.get(j));
                            displayExplosion(textView.getX(), textView.getY());
                        }
                    }
                }
                layout.removeView(textView);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: `Thread::Sleep` ?

Comment: no that dosent work was the first thing i've tried

Comment: Is this any different from your previous question [pause program between adding and removing a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58302625/pause-program-between-adding-and-removing-a-textview) and is it really necessary to post a new one?

Comment: no one answered the question

Comment: If I understood right, you need to fire 20 events with a 1-second delay between each? If that's it - `handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)` is not the right approach. It will add 20 events in the queue, that will fire all after 1 second delay with a very slight difference.

Comment: _"no one answered the question"_ That's not a reason to repeat it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pause program between adding and removing a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58302625/pause-program-between-adding-and-removing-a-textview)