# My Java object constructor returning “null”

Tags: android, object, null, rx-java

I have created a class that has constructors for various Activity. However, when I try and subscribe to the object so as to display some images and price and names of a products, I receive "null" as the output. but when i try to pass the same function in the else statement it worked but still returned null. Please help me understand why am getting this error. and tell me how to solve it Thanks in advance.

```
mCompositeDisposable.add(mIMyRestaurantAPI.getFoodOfMenu(Common.API_KEY,
                event.getCategory().getId())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(foodModel -> {

                    if (foodModel.isSuccess()) {
                        adapter = new MyFoodAdapter(this, foodModel.getResult());
                        recycler_food_list.setAdapter(adapter);
                        recycler_food_list.setLayoutAnimation(mLayoutAnimationController);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "[GET FOOD RESULT]" + foodModel.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    mDialog.dismiss();

                }, throwable -> {
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(this, "[GET FOOD]" + throwable.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }));
```

i keep getting GET FOOD RESULT=null..here is what my FOODMODEL construtor looks like

```
public class FoodModel {
private boolean success;
private String message;
private List<Food> result;

public boolean isSuccess() {
    return success;
}

public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
    this.success = success;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public List<Food> getResult() {
    return result;
}

public void setResult(List<Food> result) {
    this.result = result;
}
```

and here is what the FOOD constructor looks like

```
public class Food {

private int id;
private String name;
private String description;
private String image;
private Double price;
private boolean isSize;
private boolean isAddon;
private int discount;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public Double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(Double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public boolean isSize() {
    return isSize;
}

public void setSize(boolean size) {
    isSize = size;
}

public boolean isAddon() {
    return isAddon;
}

public void setAddon(boolean addon) {
    isAddon = addon;
}

public int getDiscount() {
    return discount;
}

public void setDiscount(int discount) {
    this.discount = discount;
}
```

and this is where i pass the connection from the backend using retrofit.

```
 @GET("food")

Observable<FoodModel> getFoodOfMenu(@Query("key") String apiKey,
                                    @Query("menuId") int menuId);
```

here is the api backend i used nodejs..

```
router.get('/food', function (req, res, next) {
if (req.query.key == API_KEY) {
    req.getConnection(function (error, conn) {
        var menu_id = req.query.menuId
        if (menu_id != null) {
            conn.query('SELECT id,name,description,image,price, CASE WHEN isSize=1 THEN \'TRUE\' ELSE \'FALSE\' END as isSize,'
                +'CASE WHEN isAddon=1 THEN \'TRUE\' ELSE \'FALSE\' END as isAddon,'
                + 'discount FROM Food WHERE Id in (SELECT foodId FROM Menu_Food WHERE MenuId=?)', [menu_id], function (err, rows, fields) {

                if (err) {
                    res.status(500)
                    res.send(JSON.stringify({ sucess: false, message: err.message }))
                }
                else {
                    if (rows.length > 0) {
                        res.send(JSON.stringify({ sucess: true, result: rows }))
                    }
                    else {
                        res.send(JSON.stringify({ sucess: false, message: "Empty" }))
                    }
                }
            })
        } else {
            res.send(JSON.stringify({ sucess: false, message: "Missing menu_id" }))
        }
    })
}
else {
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: false, message: "Wrong api key marfe" }))
}
```

})

here is the json response

```
{"sucess":true,"result":[{"id":1,"name":"ROASTED QUARTER CHICKEN","description":"Served with mushroom gravy, cranberry & mint sauces","image":"http://10.0.2.2:3000/4_roasted_quarter_chicken_with_special_sauces.jpg","price":25,"isSize":"FALSE","isAddon":"FALSE","discount":0},{"id":2,"name":"CURRY CHICKEN","description":"Chicken served in curry that is made from more than 10 spices to bring out the authentic traditional taste. Served with rice and 3 side dishes\r\n","image":"http://10.0.2.2:3000/2_curry_chic.jpg","price":25,"isSize":"FALSE","isAddon":"FALSE","discount":0},{"id":3,"name":"\r\nRENDANG CHICKEN","description":"Simmered chicken in spices. Served with rice and 3 side dishes","image":"http://10.0.2.2:3000/1_classic_rendang.jpg","price":25,"isSize":"FALSE","isAddon":"FALSE","discount":0},{"id":4,"name":"HERBAL STEAMED CHICKEN","description":"Steamed chicken with red dates and mushroom. Served with rice and 3 side dishes","image":"http://10.0.2.2:3000/3_herbal_steamed_chic.jpg","price":25,"isSize":"FALSE","isAddon":"FALSE","discount":0}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be getting null from the api response. 
Or your Java Object and its fields should match the attributes in your json response.

For example you have this json`{
  "countries": [
    {
      "name": "Israel",
      "phoneCode": "972",
      "code": "IL"
    },
    {
      "name": "Afghanistan",
      "phoneCode": "93",
      "code": "AF"
    },
    {
      "name": "Albania",
      "phoneCode": "355",
      "code": "AL"
    }]}`

Then your model would be like this

```
public class CountryModel {

private List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<>();

public List<Country> getCountries() {
    return countries;
}

public void setCountries(List<Country> countries) {
    this.countries = countries;
}

public static class Country {
    private String name;
    private String code;
    private String phoneCode;

    public Country(String name, String code, String phoneCode) {
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
        this.phoneCode = phoneCode;
    }


    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhoneCode() {
        return phoneCode;
    }

    public void setPhoneCode(String phoneCode) {
        this.phoneCode = phoneCode;
    }

}
```

}

with your json your Java model should look like this

```
public class Example {

private Boolean sucess;
private List<Result> result = null;

public Boolean getSucess() {
return sucess;
}

public void setSucess(Boolean sucess) {
this.sucess = sucess;
}

public List<Result> getResult() {
return result;
}

public void setResult(List<Result> result) {
this.result = result;
}

}
```

Comment: private boolean success;
private String message; See your json does not have these attributes. Thats why you are getting null

Comment: so should i make it public boolen success or what do you think is the best way to solve it sir.. please am a bit lost

Comment: Like in your java model you have 'success' field but in your json you are getting 'sucess' so it will not get parsed with 'success'

Comment: please tell me how i can am new to stackoverflow